# How can I export data from ajax function into an express js server

Tags: ajax, xml, express, import, export

How can I send data from a separate js file into my server in express js?

I'm trying to parse an xml file with ajax/jquery and send the data to an express js server. The parser sits in a separate file under /public/javascripts. I get this error message: ReferenceError: module is not defined.

This is an excerpt from parseBooks.js where I make the ajax call:

```
module.exports= {
   parseBook: function(){
     $(function(){ 
     ....
```

and then in my app.js server I require the file in question:

```
var bookParser= var bookParser= require('./public/javascripts/parseBooks');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a jQuery post, with your data variable containing a string representation of the xml?

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

For more details: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: No it's not even loading jquery. I put an alert() after the $(function) and it's not working. I guess my question is: can we export a jquery/ajax call into a server at all?